# Application deployed in tomcat cannot be started through Jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, tomcat, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've deployed an application deployed in tomcat and want to restart and hence stop it first and then start it with following code -

```
def startServer() {
    withEnv(['JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontkill']) {
        script {
            sh '''
    cd "$CATALINA_HOME/bin"
    export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms4096m -Xmx1100m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
    ./catalina.sh start'''
        }
    }
}
```

Through Jenkins, server is not started but if same commands are executed manually server is started.

Could you please help to understand what could be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Is Jenkins stopping the app? What are the startup errors? I'm not sure, but this is due to the fact that after executing the command, the session closes and the process dies